# How to display date as YYYYMMDD_HH24 using Solaris shell command?

Tags: solaris, datetime-format

```
20110216_00

20110216_01

...

20110216_23


20110217_00
..
```

and so on

I have tried with

```
date +'%Y%m%d_%H'
```

but it never starts with 00-23 format but from 01-24 like format, hence I get hour part always incorrect.

Can anybody suggest, how can I get above o/p

Comment: First, what shell? sh, bash? Then that "'Y" looks like it is missing a leading "%". And the "date" and "+" needs a space between them. Anyway %H should work in bash. Do not forget that 'date' command might be reimplemented in the shell, so use /bin/date or whatever place Solaris puts the 'date' command.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I have edited date command above & its a bash shell on solaris...  My problem here is i should get hours start from 00.  means The hour field display 00 for 12 a.m. to 23 for 11 p.m.

Comment: It is strange, because %H displays hours from 00 in Bash in Ubuntu. What is your system locale? And check the origin & version of 'date.

Comment: Solaris date command uses strftime which processes correctly the %H conversion format, i.e. 00 - 23. Can you provide more evidence about what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

What revision of Solaris are you using?  It is roughly 22:30 locally and I see:

```
mph@sol11express:~$ date +'%Y%m%d_%H'
20110216_22
mph@sol11express:~$ uname -a
SunOS sol11express 5.11 snv_151a i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
mph@sol11express:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

which looks to me like it is using 0-23 for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by manupulating the hour part. Check the snip below.

```
#/bin/ksh
s=`date +'%Y%m%d_'`
t=` date +'%H'`
let t=$t+1
echo "Required date is " $s$t
```

It gives

```
Required date is  20110316_16
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on SunOS 5.10 This works !

```
date +%Y%m%d_%H
-> 20130912_02

date +'%Y%m%d_%H'
-> 20130912_02
```

Can you tell us which Solaris are you using ?

```
uname -a
```

Cheers !

Answer (score -1):

you can use date -u +'%Y-%m-%d-%H'